# SCP command not working - need to copy file from Windows localhost to Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, window, scp

I need to copy file admin.zip from C:\wamp\www\jdhemumbai060714\webfiles (Windows) to /var/www/html/ (Linux). I am using following command::

```
scp C:\wamp\www\jdhemumbai060714\webfiles\admin.zip username@hostname:/var/www/html/
```

But it does not work and gives error::

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I am logged in Linux server using SSH

Answer (score 5):

I think that it is bug in SCP port. 
Only way is skip "C:" and use only "\wamp\www\jdhemumbai060714\webfiles\admin.zip"
It will work if current directory is on the same disk like file for upload.
Or you can use [pscp.exe](http://www.nber.org/pscp.html)

Comment: That was actually my problem. SCP seems to take everything before the ":" as a hostname instead of the windows drive letter. I did just started CMD from the target folder and instead of defining the local folder I just typed "." for the current folder.

Answer (score 3):

high likely You were using scp in linux shell logged in via ssh, close connection by exit and in windows cmd with admin rights use the same command, then scp will ask for root password for connection and will confirm if file was found and sent

Answer (score 2):

Well firstly is your DNS server able to resolve the HOSTNAME your copying too? My Advice would be to use IP Address.

```
scp C:\wamp\www\jdhemumbai060714\webfiles\admin.zip username@192.168.0.2:/var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

BELOW ANSWER APPLICABLE ONLY FOR EC2 OR WHICH HAS PEM KEY.

Open Windows CMD, and Type

scp -i Keypair_Along_with_Path.pem YOUR_FILENAME_ALONG_WITH_PATH.txt USERNAME@PUBLIC-IP:DESTINATION_PATH

**Real Example:**
scp -i C:\Users\Keypair.pem C:\Users\File.txt ubuntu@1.1.1.1:/tmp/.

You are done.